# item-not-found(404) in sending file(Image) using ASMACK android

Tags: android, asmack

I am trying to send image file in my chat application . i am using asmack-android-8-4.0.6.jar .Log in and normal messaging works great but i am not able to send image . There is no fatal exception but i always get item-not-found(404) message I am using following code

```
 public void sendFile(String picturePath, String to)
{
                CustomLogger.showLog("Bitmap", "path is " + picturePath);
                CustomLogger.showLog("Bitmap", "path is " + to);
                if (xmppConnection == null)
                {
                    CustomLogger.showLog("Service", "connection is null while sending image");
                }
                else
                {
                    CustomLogger.showLog("Service", "connection is not null while sending image");
                    FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(xmppConnection, true);
                    manager = new FileTransferManager(xmppConnection);
                    manager.addFileTransferListener(this);
                    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(to + "/sc");
                    File file = new File(picturePath);

                    try
                    {
                       transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        CustomLogger.showLog("Bitmap", "Exception in sending file");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    while (!transfer.isDone())
                    {
                        if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error))
                        {
                            CustomLogger.showLog("Bitmap", "ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
                        }
                        else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)
                                || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused))
                        {
                            CustomLogger.showLog("Bitmap", "Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(1000L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)
                            || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled))
                    {
                        CustomLogger.showLog("Bitmap", "refused cancelled error " +""+transfer.getError()+"  " + transfer.getException());
                        transfer.getException().printStackTrace();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CustomLogger.showLog("Bitmap", "Success in sending");
                    }
                }
            }
```

And the stack trace is

```
item-not-found
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:196)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5BytestreamManager.establishSession(Socks5BytestreamManager.java:493)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.Socks5TransferNegotiator.createOutgoingStream(Socks5TransferNegotiator.java:63)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:386)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer.access$100(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:35)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer$2.run(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:220)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your aSmack version is very old. I suggest to use the latest stable (which is 4.0.6 at the time of writing), where you don't have to configure Smack's ProviderManager. You should also post the stacktrace of the exception in which `item-not-found` is wrapped. A full trace of the exchanged stanzas is also very helpful. More information about XMPP file transfer with Smack can be found at https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-XMPP-File-Transfer

Comment: @Flow thanks for the response. i will try ASMACk 4.0.6

Comment: @Flow with new jar i am facing problems with connecting and log in. need to figure it out that first

Comment: @Flow i have updated the code and using jar 4.0.6 but still error is same . i have uploaded the stack trace as well